# Writing a custom ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel, listcellrenderer

I want to write a custom ListCellRenderer.

Only thing that needs to be different from the default one is that it doesn't display the return value of `value.toString()`, but eturn value of `value.myOwnCustomMethodThatReturnsString()`.

What is the simplest way of doing that?

The class all this is in already implements ListCellRenderer and I have:

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Chapter> list,
        Chapter value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
{
    return null;
}
```

I just don't know what to put inbetween the brackets...

Comment: yes I understand, no issue, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for myOwnCustomMethodThatReturnsString() as local variable.

Comment: @mKorbel really no need for that in current issue

Comment: @SeniorJD this works as complex in two three cases that I can't see in your code nor from description, but nobody knows in Swing is everything possible, otherwise OPs returns with a new question about

Comment: @Karlovsky120 basically nothing to do with an SSCCE in your case, you totally ingnore that, isn't it, but there are two important reasons 1. for another readers 2. to reduce 10mio possibilities to one - two out of record you need to fill XxxListModel from two dimensional array

Comment: @mKorbel in most cases YES, you're right. But this one question doesn't require it as well ;)

Comment: @SeniorJD *"question doesn't require it"*  It's good then, that mKorbel never implied it does.  The exact words used were *"for better help sooner"*, and as far as getting an answer, it helps to encourage people to copy/paste the code so they might get an answer sooner. It also allows people who provide answers to check there solution compiles and runs, which in turn leads to better answers.  I note you already entered a correct answer, great.  But that doesn't change the correctness or wisdom of the advice offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Chapter> list, Chapter value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
       Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

       if (c instanceof Jlabel) { // it would work because DefaultListCellRenderer usually returns instance of JLabel
           ((JLabel)c).setText(value.myOwnCustomMethodThatReturnsString()); 
       }

       return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s even easier to replace the `value` object with the custom `String` before invoking `super.getListCellRendererComponent`. Then you don’t need to mess with the JLabel.

Comment: @Holger easier, but not more correct. For current case, you're right of course ;)

Comment: @Karlovsky120 in case if you have a complex `Renderer` system and your super class is not a `DefaultListCellRenderer`, so it requires full info about your `Chapter` object, for example.